# Overflow-x does not work

Tags: html, css, scroll

This is my **code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bigbox {
      width:1024px;
      height:600px;
      background-color:#000000;
      overflow-x:auto;
      overflow-y:hidden;
    }
    .box{
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#AAAAAA;
      margin:5px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bigbox">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make all **box** display horizontally?

And the **bigbox** has a `scroll bar` with the `width` fixed.

I have tried to change the width to 5000px, and it work, but the width is over the boxes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/okUVxFep)***   -- ***[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Rkue9/)***

HI now add some **properties**

**as like this**

```
    .bigbox {
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .box{
    float:left;  // remove this line 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    }
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/okUVxFep)***

Comment: +1. Nice solution, with pure CSS. I was trying to do the same but I was missing the "white-space:nowrap", which seems necessary to make it work. Without that line, the boxes display horizontally only if there is enough space in the page, but if there is no space some of the boxes will go to a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `.box div` `display:inline-block;`

```
.bigbox {
      width:400px;
      height:600px;
      background-color:#000000;
      overflow-x:auto;
      overflow-y:hidden;
      white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .box{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      float:left;
      background-color:#AAAAAA;
      margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    }​
```

**[Edited Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WMzsu/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the result I want is all the **boxes** display horizontally with only 1 row.

Answer (score -1):

Best and easiest way (as far as  I know) is to wrap all `.box` elements and define their parent width as the sum of all his children's width.

In your code example it would be:

CSS:

```
.boxview {
    width: 3060px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bigbox">
  <div class="boxview">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the number of boxes is not prefixed then I suggest you use JavaScript to set `.boxview` width dynamically.

Also notice `overflow-x` will not work on older browsers (IE9+ only).

You might wanna add `overflow: auto` before defining `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` as a fallback.

**Code example**: http://jsfiddle.net/zvs4H/1/

Comment: Is there any other way instead using js?

Comment: When are the boxes added? Do you know how much will be there in advance?

Comment: I generate the boxes using PHP, the boxes sum depend on the `Database` records, so it's hard for me to use js for setting the width

Comment: You can define `.boxview` width as a really big number. Not sure how old browsers would react to it.

Comment: You could give `.boxview` inline-styling with the desired width. Not the best practice though.